# Videocon sim not supported in my Nokia Lumia 520

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-phone-8

I have recently bought a new Nokia Lumia 520. I use videocon cellular network but when I used the sim in lumia 520, the phone could not search the signal.

What I tried: 
1. I used other cellular network sim (eg. vodafone) in my phone, which worked.
2. I used the videocon sim in other lumia's which is working perfectly fine.
3. Replaced the videocon sim with a brand new sim. Even now the lumia does not support videocon sim.

It's just that the phone is not supporting a single cellular network. I do not want to change my cellular operator, what should I do ?

Comment: Are you sure the phone even supprts the cellular network in question.

Comment: @Ramhound Is there a way I can find it out ?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, in other lumia 520's the videocon sim is working fine